# Two-way binding not working on an Aurelia Custom Attribute

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to implement [this solution given by Jeremy Danyow for dirty checking](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/issues/160).  I'm using TypeScript so I've adapted his code as best I can.  For some reason, the `isDirty` flag on my VM is not being updated.  Here is what I have:

**agency.ts - (my vm)**

```
export class Agency {
    public isDirty : boolean = false;
    public agency : IAgency = null;

    ...
}
```

**agency.html - (my view)**

```
<template>
   <require from="../resources/attributes/dirty"></require>
    ${isDirty}                                <== Always displays false
    <form dirty.two-way="isDirty">            <== have also tried dirty.bind
         <div class="input-group">
               <label>Agency Name</label>
               <input type="text" value.bind="agency.name" />
         </div>
         ... 
    </form>
    <div if.bind="isDirty">
         <button>Save Changes</button>
         <button>Undo Changes</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

**dirty.ts - (the attribute)**

```
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class DirtyCustomAttribute{
   private view: any;
   private bindings: any[] = [];
   @bindable({defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) value: any;

   static inject = [Element]
   constructor(public element : HTMLElement) {}

   created(view) {
      this.view = view;
   }

   bind() {  
    this.bindings = this.view.bindings
        .filter(b => b.mode === bindingMode.twoWay && this.element.contains(b.target));

    let i = this.bindings.length;
    let self = this;
    while (i--) {
        let binding = this.bindings[i];
        binding.dirtyTrackedUpdateSource = binding.updateSource;
        binding.updateSource = function (newValue) {
            this.dirtyTrackedUpdateSource(newValue);
            if (!self.value) {
                self.value = true;
            }
        }
    }
   }

   unbind() { // See code in referenced link }
}
```

So, using logging, I can see that the `updateSource()` code is being called and the `self.value` flag is being set.  However, the `div` with the buttons in my view is never displayed and the `${isDirty}` template always displays false.  It would seem that the `dirty.two-way="isDirty"` is not two-way binding like it should.

Where am I going wrong?

**Update**

So it appears it might be due to compose so I'll add the extra code to show how this is being composed.

**shell.ts**

```
export class Shell
{
    public agencies : IAgency[] = []; //loaded in activate
    public tablist : any[] = [
        {title: "Detail", vm: PLATFORM.moduleName("./agency") },
         ...
    ];
    public selectedAgency : IAgency = null;
    public selectedVM : any = this.tablist[0];

}
```

**shell.html**

```
<template>
    ...
    <compose view-model.bind="selectedVM.vm" model.bind="selectedAgency"></compose>
</template>
```

**agency.ts (additional)**

```
activate(model){
    this.agency = model;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I didn't find anything wrong with your code regarding the custom attribute. I made a codesandbox and your code seems to be doing what you want. Please take a look at https://codesandbox.io/embed/bi-directional-value-converters-v3b50?fontsize=14 so you can observe if there is any difference to determine the cause.

Comment: So it must have to do with my use of `<compose>`.  I left that part out for simplicity but `Agency` vm is being composed within another vm.  I was trying to test that on your `codesandbox` sample but I can't seem to get `<compose>` to work in that environment.

Comment: I've had no luck in the past getting two-way binding to work with compose. You might want to wire up an event aggregator or a service if it turns out to not be possible. The documentation [here](https://aurelia.io/docs/templating/dynamic-ui-composition#basic-composition) does **not** mention you can pass back data.